# Is it a possible for an objective-c class to implement a swift protocol in the .h

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is it a possible for an `Objective-C` class to implement a `Swift` protocol in the `.h` so that other `Swift` classes can reference the `Objective-C` class by the `Swift` protocol type?

Let `MySwiftProtocol` be the `Swift` protocol type, now assume I have this in `.h` for my class:

```
@protocol MySwiftProtocol;
@interface MyObj : NSObject< MySwiftProtocol>
```

Then I'll get a warning: `cannot find protocol definition for MySwiftProtocol`
The warning is no good, so that doesn't work.

So let's assume I do this in the `.m` and remove the references to the protocol in the `.h`.

```
@interface MyObj () <MySwiftProtocol>
```

Then I end up not being able to cast objects of type `MyObj` to type `MySwiftProtocol` in `Swift` classes.

So neither approach above works.

Please help!

Comment: is this code part of an app or framework target?

Comment: The protocol and the class are a part of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to apple.  `Forward declarations of Swift classes and protocols can only be used as types for method and property declarations`.  Further apple says, `An Objective-C class can adopt a Swift protocol in its implementation (.m) file by importing the Xcode generated header for Swift code...`

Basically you cannot mark an obj-c class as conforming to a swift protocol in the .h.   So you must do it in the .m and then have the class pass itself to any object that is expecting a reference the objc object as the swift protocol type.

See sections `Referencing a Swift Class or Protocol in an Objective-C Header` and `Adopting a Swift Protocol in an Objective-C Implementation`  at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Can you post a link to the docs with those quotes? Last time I had a similar problem I couldn't find a good documentation about it.

Comment: Sorry, found this info first while reading the iBooks version of "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.2)"  I just posted the link in the answer above.