# Obj-C - Import (Swift Compiler Recognise?)

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm migrating from Obj-C to Swift and have just migrated from PSGameScene.h and PSGameScene.m to GameScene.swift.

When I build the app, I get an error stating that PSGameScene isn't a recognised symbol.

GameScene.swift is added to the "compile list", I've tried adding GameSCene-swift.h to the source, but it doesn't see it..

Where am I going wrong?

I can confirm that both the bridging header and the .swift file area added to the compile scheme.

In the .h and .m files, it does recognise the class, and when I imoprt trying to use (GameScene-swift.s it complains that the file isn't there...

I'm. little lost...

Any posters would be helpful...

Cheers,

A

Comment: Did you add `#import "PSGameScene.h"` to the bridging header?

Comment: When you say you've "migrated from PSGameScene.h and PSGameScene.m to GameScene.swift," do you mean you've rewritten your old code in Swift or that you're trying to import ObjC classes from `PSGameScene.h` in `GameScene.swift`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use your new Swift class in Objective-C, check out this [answer about how to mix and match the two in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124556/335974).

The gist is: import the generated `-Swift.h` header in your `.m` file that you want to use the Swift class on (you can't import it in a `.h`, check the above answer for more):

```
// SomeImplementationFile.m
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

You can double check the name of your `-Swift.h` header in Build Settings / Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm well aware of how to import Swift to Obj-C and the limitations. It turned out that  because it was an old project, the `DEFINES_MODULE` was set to `NO` or `Defines Module` in build settings. I guess the newer Xcode releases overlooked that when upgrading the project...

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be related to the build settings. As `defines module` was set to `NO`, it didn't like the import. When the `DEFINES_MODULE` (`defines module`) setting was set to `YES` it all clicked into place.

This probably happened as it related to an old project which spans back to Xcode 4 days. It appears that the newer releases of Xcode don't take into account some settings.

Thanks for the answers..